# Ruby cucumber automation suite - parameter received as null while iterating

Tags: ruby, cucumber, automated-tests, watir

I inherited a test automation suite and while modifying it I am trying to write a function to test similar links which are present in the same web page but in different divs and the tag ids are dynamic.

I have a function defined below which accepts an HTML element and sends an action to the element

```
 def element_do(html_element, html_element_type, html_element_value, action)
   @browser.send(html_element.to_sym,html_element_type.to_sym ,html_element_value).send(action) 
 end
```

I have a method defined as somemethod and I am trying to call the method in a particular div using the some_element#{i} as below

```
def multiple_accounts
  @num_accts.each do |i|
    p "validating for account #{i}"
    @page.element_do(:div,:id,"some_element#{i}",somemethod)
  end
```

The issue I am facing is that on second iteration the action parameter is passed as `null` instead of the `somemethod`. I am new to ruby automation and I am not sure what exactly is happening. Any help is appreciated

Additional details - based on the questions 
1) @num_accts is an array which is got by scanning the text of the webpage and contains account numbers (eg: [56544, 87990])

2) This forms a part of the id for the divs as in "acct#56544". So I am passing the array elements from num_accts to "acct#{i}" referred as 'some_element'

3) 'Somemethod' is a method defined to click on a particular link in the div and verifies a text to confirm that the link redirects to the correct page. The some method works fine when there is only one div.

Comment: What exactly is `somemethod`? The `multiple_accounts` method suggests it's a local variable, but not defined?

Comment: have you considered adding to the puts you are using for debugging, and having it indicate what is in somemethod as well as i? e.g. `p "validating for account: #{i} using method: #{somemethod}"` (and btw, a more descriptive variable name than 'i' would make it clearer to others what kind of thing was held in the collection you are iterating over.)

Comment: I have updated the question with the comments regarding the different elements. Thank you

Comment: @apprentice_RR, you still need to share what `somemethod` actually is. Given that `somemethod` is the method returning the wrong result, I would think that is where we should be debugging.

Comment: @JustinKo - The method verifies whether a text is present on the new page opened by clicking the link.   ~def somemethod~
~    page.fail_unless(@page.text_exists?("My text"), "fail Not on 'this' page", "10") ~
~    page.click_element(:link, :text, "this link") ~
~        fail "Not on this page" unless page.text_exists?("FAQ") &&     page.text_exists?("Frequently asked questions") ~
~    page.closeBrowser ~
~    end ~

Answer (score 0):

It is not evident from the question, but my suspicion is that you try to pass the name of the method (which returns `null`), but instead you call the method. I think your call should be:

```
@page.element_do(:div,:id,"some_element#{i}",'somemethod')
```

Comment: When I try to include it as a call it errors out saying 'undefined method for Watir element'. However when I try to pass the method as a parameter the  method gets called in the first iteration but errors out on the second as the value is received as 'Null'

Comment: That's because the method should be defined on the element class. This is simply how it's implemented... I suspect what you want to be done is not possible using the API you are trying to use...

Comment: Thank you. It seems that this cannot be implemented